# set custom variable for tomcat8

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I want to set a custom variable for my application in tomcat, and use `System.getProperty` in java to get it.

I tried :

- MyV=test OR export MyV=test in setenv.sh
- export -DMyV=test in
  catalina.sh
- export JAVA_OPTS="-DMyV=test" in catalina.sh

all above are not working, System.getProperty("MyV") always returns null when I start or debug tomcat.

so, what should I do to get the value of `MyV`,thank you!

**My operation system is OS X, JDK version is 1.8 and I start tomcat in Eclipse.**

Comment: How do you start Tomcat in Eclipse? This is where you need to set the variable. Exporting arbitrary variables to your shell is very unlikely to make a difference. P.S. using system properties in a web server is probably not the best course of action.

Comment: I set tomcat to the `servers` window of Eclipse, and click the button `restart the server`.

Answer (score -1):

You should try the JAVA_OPTS without quotes JAVA_OPTS=-DMyV=test

Comment: thank you. I've tried `export JAVA_OPTS=-DMyV=test`  into `catalina.sh` or `setenv.sh`, but it's not working, java still returns null...

Comment: Are you running tomcat in linux? Is it running as service? Then you need to change in the script that runs the service.

Comment: I'm running tomcat within the **server** view of the **Eclipse**, I think it will use the _catalina.sh_  file, my operation system is **OS X** based on unix.

Comment: If you are running tomcat in eclipse, then you should get into the tomcat run time environment in and add the options,

Comment: How? when I'm starting tomcat in eclipse, shouldn't it use `catalina.sh` to start the tomcat?

Comment: It does not. You typically create a tomcat server and runtime environment. open the server configuration and you will see runtime environment. chage the options there